# Multiples vHosts with XAMPP 1.7.3

Tags: apache, xampp, php-5.3, vhosts

I'm trying to configure multiple vhosts on a machine on my network , however, no matter what I use to access servername , the apacche always directs to the first host.

Here it's my vHosts file

```
<VirtualHost eurekahom:7777>
    DocumentRoot "d:\vhosts\eurekahom\controller/"
    ServerName eurekahom

 #   RewriteEngine On
 #   RewriteOptions Inherit

    <Directory />
        AllowOverride All    
    </Directory> 

    php_value include_path ".;d:\vhosts\eurekahom\controller\includes/"
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost eurekades:7777>
    DocumentRoot "d:\vhosts\eurekades\controller/"
    ServerName eurekades

    <Directory />
        AllowOverride All    
    </Directory>

    php_value include_path ".;d:\vhosts\eurekades\controller\includes/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost mauricio:7777>
    DocumentRoot "d:\htdocs\mauricio" 
    #\controller/"
    ServerName mauricio

 #   RewriteEngine On
 #   RewriteOptions Inherit

    <Directory />
        AllowOverride All    
    </Directory> 

    php_value include_path ".;d:\htdocs\mauricio"
</VirtualHost>
```

Did anyone know what's happend?

Comment: That looks like it should work. Are you restarting apache? Are there any errors in the log? Do you have `Listen *:7777` somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe for virtual hosts there are IP-based matching and server name matching. So whatever you type here: `<VirtualHost ________:7777>` should be an IP address. Since you don't want to match by IP, you can just leave a `*:7777`.

So yes, all your statements will start with `<VirtualHost *:7777>`. When a request comes for that 7777 port, Apache will then try to match by server name, and then the `ServerName` parameter will be considered.

There might be more issues with the `<Directory>` statement too, but I believe that is not what was causing Apache to always use the first VirtualHost all the time.

The following link is very useful, as it helped me when I had a very similar problem:
https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/CommonMisconfigurations

Answer (score 0):

I usually don't specify the host name in the VirtualDirectory element, instead leaving it at `*:7777`

Also, for directories outside my `htdocs` folder, I use additional Directory options:

```
<Directory "C:\Projects\spacelysprockets">
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```